# Verb for looking for meaning where there is none

Tags: meaning, verbs

I vaguely remember using a verb that meant "to look for meaning in something that lacks meaning or has none".

I can't remember what the specific word is, but I do remember using it to suggest my English teacher's career was a pointless waste. She was not happy. :)

Comment: Nothing specific to *meaning*, but more generically: *futile*, *fruitless*, and synonyms. But if you find it, let me know, as I'll edit it into [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/305140/55623) and any future ones attempting to interpret PoMo gibberish.

Answer (score -2):

Split into two answers as my rep is not yet high enough to post more than two links.

[Read into](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/read-into)?

[Over-analyze](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=overanalyze&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=e7ZXWLfMIuKm8wenoqugDA)?

Continued below.

Answer (score -3):

[Justify](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/justify)? See definition 5.

[Rationalize](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=rationalize&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5LZXWJ_ABuKm8wenoqugDA)?

Interestingly enough, I feel like I'm reading too much into this question in my rationalized over-analysis. But perhaps this is just my justification for posting so many links.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. And we want answers on the site, not at the other end of a link.