# Literary devices and sentence structure in Matthew 7:1 (KJV)

Tags: transitive-verbs, literary-device

I am a student who is looking for help on a specific portion of my discussion. I have been asked the following questions with respect [to this KJV verse](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207%3A1-5&version=KJV):

> Judge not, that ye be not judged.
>   -- Matthew 7:1kjv

- What specific literary devices are used in this scripture?
- What is the order of the sentence structure?

In particular for this second question, I have been up for the past few hours attempting to determine if *judge not* is being used as a transitive verb.

Comment: I downvoted this for two reasons. First, this, at a glance, appears to be work someone has assigned you to do. If that’s the case, then *you should do it*, not try to palm it off to strangers on the internet. As tedious as it is, homework has a purpose, and shirking it defeats that purpose, which only hurts you, whether you can see this now or will have to wait 20 years (said as s reformed homework shirker; trust me). If that’s not the case, we need you to [edit] this Q and give us background and context as to where this Q arose, and why you need it answered. Help us give you more helpful As.

Comment: The second reason, which applies regardless of whether this is homework or not, is you haven’t shown any evidence of your own effort or research to answer the question yourself. On this site, you must always do that, both out of foundational courtesy but more importantly again because it’ll help us give you more focused and valuable answers.  The KJV bible has been analyzed in great detail by millions of scholars for centuries. You can find dozens of commentaries on this verse or any other with a google search. Go do that, and come back and tell us what you found and what questions remain.

Comment: First, thank you for your quick response. I am indeed a student who is looking for help on a specific portion of my discussion. I have not simply resorted to "shirking" my assignment, as I have been up for the past few hours (now with a headache) seeking the right way to decipher each of the literary devices used in the previously mentioned bible verse. Specifically, I'm not sure if "judge not" is being used as a transitive verb. As trivial as this may seem to you, it has become quite complicated for me as I am tired and boarding a tiny bit of frustration.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and honest response. Taking that into account, you’ll get a lot better reception if you [edit] your Q to mention that it’s the transitive nature of the verb “judge not” which is the issue you’re struggling with, and lay out your conflicting thoughts about why it is or isn’t; your current reasoning and conundrum. You should also still mention that this is an assignment (ie provide background and context). And if you’re still interested in the literary devices employed, over and above the question of grammar, describe what research you’ve done into that and what you’ve found.

Comment: (And, btw, questions of grammar are hardly *ever* trivial, and no one on this site, myself included, would ever make such a claim or judge a question based on that thought. In fact, for native speakers like me, analyzing grammar is usually more difficult than for people who have studied English formally, by the “rules”, as opposed to just intuition derived from exposure. No one is judging your question “too trivial”.)

Comment: I was typing a follow-up to my post that I see now did not post. I meant to say that the subject matter of this post may have seemed less complex in nature in comparison to other posts, and not that you viewed it as trivial. That would be contradictory to your purpose, being that you provide the platform for me to receive help. (I hope that makes sense.) I even see that I made a mistake by typing "boarding" instead of "bordering on". Again, I am quite tired and trying to focus on completing this assignment. I can see that it's showing in my writing. My apologies.

Comment: So now, is my instruction from you to resubmit my post with the added pieces of information you've provided? Or, is this just advice for future submissions?

Comment: It's for both, but because you've shown such good faith here, I'll retract my downvote, add an upvote, and see if I can muster the scholarship for an answer (no promises on that, it may be beyond me).  I may also edit some bits from your comments into your question for the sake of others.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your assistance. This discussion has helped me wake up a little. I'm no longer frustrated. Hopefully, this can help my mental juices to start flowing again. =)

Comment: Here are the many translations of this verse: https://www.biblestudytools.com/matthew/7-1-compare.html

Comment: Upvoted this q and its answers because they combine to form the sort of material I'd like to see more of in this stack, in contrast with the surfeit of single-word-requests.

Answer (score 10):

The literary device at play in your cited verse is [*parallelism*](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-parallelism-in-literature-definition-examples.html), much stricter in the original Koiné:

> [Μὴ κρίνετε ἵνα μὴ κριθῆτε](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/7-1.htm)
>
> mē krinete hina mē krithēte
> *Not (y’all) judge so that not (y’all) should be judged.*

As a much more inflected language than English, the Greek dispenses with both subject pronouns, in this case second person plural, while the passive subjunctive “you should be judged” is a single word.

Unlike the language of the KJV or Shakespeare, present day English does not express negative imperatives without *do*-support: “don’t judge” rather than “judge not.” Thus if you wanted to modernize the proverb “Waste not, want not,” it would become the much more cumbersome “Don’t waste anything and you won’t lack anything.”

Comment: “No waste, no loss?” “Don”t waste, don’t lack?” “Waste nothing, want nothing?”

Answer (score 8):

### Transitivity of "judge not"

[Webster's 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/judge) cites this verse as an example of the transitive form of the verb *judge*¹:

> **JUDGE**, *verb transitive*
>
> 3. To censure rashly; to pass severe sentence.
>      *JUDGE not, that ye be not judged*. Matthew 7:1.

### Literary devices employed

One literary device (and as other answers will no doubt demonstrate, there can be several) being employed here is ***polyptoton***.

From [*The CopyBot*](https://thecopybot.com/literary-devices-web-style/), which actually uses this verse as an exemplar of this device:

> ***Polyptoton* is unique in that it’s a repetition of the root word**. For example, you can use similar words like “strength” and “strong” instead of just repeating the same word.
>
> "Judge not, that ye be not judged.”
>    Matthew 7:1

Of course, the entire passage has passed into the English canon of *aphorisms*², but this term doesn't capture any specific devices in the saying itself, it describes the saying, ex-post-facto, in terms of the English-speaking world's attitude towards it. But it's worth pointing out anyway.

#### A deeper reading

There's a case to be made that there's a deeper structure here, which warrants attention.

In *[Text to Text Pours Forth Speech: Voices of Scripture in Luke-Acts](https://books.google.com/books?id=uHuH2DSCAzsC&lpg=PA27&ots=r5yQsXgYS3&dq=%2B%22judge%20not%22%20%22literary%20device%22&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q=%20%22judge%20not%22%20%22literary%20device%22&f=false)*  by Robert L. Brawley (published 1995), 3rd chapter entitled <sub><sup>FALLING AND FITTING SHOES: *MISE EN ABYME* AND VOICES OF SCRIPTURE IN LUKE 20:9-19</sup></sub>, we read:

> The parable as a brief narrative embedded in a larger narrative **is an explanatory variant on the text that contains it** — a literary device dubbed *mise en abyme*.
>   ...
>   In its negative form, the aphorism runs, **judge not, that you be not judged**.

This is an interesting take.  It it saying that the final part of the aphorism *that you be not judged*, is an embedding of a smaller part which reflects the larger text which contains it. A so-called *mise en abyme*.

This is a useful reading, to my mind, especially considering Wikipedia's definition of the device:

> ***Mise en abyme*** (French pronunciation: ​[miz‿ɑ̃n‿abim]; also mise en abîme) is a term used in Western art history to describe **a formal technique of placing a copy of an image within itself,**

[image: Example of *mise en abyme*, a photo of a hand holding a photo of a hand holding...]

Of course, this definition explicitly constrains the device to the visual arts, but I am inclined to endorse Brawley's extension here³.

---

¹ <sub>Unfortunately, I can offer this at no more than face value. More detailed grammatical analysis will have to come from our resident synctacticians.</sub>

²  <sub>From Collins: ***[aphorism](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/aphorism)***: *An aphorism is a short witty sentence which expresses a general truth or comment*.</sub>

³ <sub>Which is saying a lot, as I am [not predisposed to sympathize with the PoMo project of deconstruction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305137/meaning-of-un-work/305140#305140).</sub>

Comment: That mise en abîme here is a bit of a stretch.  It just means self-reference, either visually or through language. The funny thing is that un abîme is an abyss, chasm, gulf or depths.  So there you have all the French weirdness one might want....:). It's authorial narcissism, basically. Or navel gazing, some might say.

Comment: @Lambie I agree it's a stretch, but it's a stretch I like :)  Brawley makes a good case for it (but you have to read a bit more of the work in the Google Books link, which is outright painful). But moreover, I think the verse *does* have a recursive, reflective structure: we are judged by our judging; in judging, we are judged. To get out of the chasm, we have to *stop digging* :)

Comment: There is a tension between the current state of the text and its likely transmission. The aphorism reflecting its narrative frame is the canonical shape, but the narrative frame was most likely added to set up the aphorism, similar to a Jewish exegetical method called _midrash_. Both are valid ways to look at the text.

Comment: @KarlG I am sorry, I do not understand you. I am not familiar enough with exegesis or rhetoric.

Answer (score 8):

[KariG's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/470235/55623) is very important, though the questioner does not have ready access to it.

The original Greek has *absolutely no literary device*.  It is plain Greek.  Translating into the same plain English, it says "Don't judge in order not to be judged .  The questioner is being asked to think himself back into the time (and grammar) of Stuart England to decide what in the language of that time counts as a literary device.  Quite a task.

I found a useful study of this topic by Chung-hye Han in [Diachronic Syntax: Models and Mechanisms](http://www.sfu.ca/~chunghye/papers/digs.pdf), eds., Anthony Warne, Susan Pintzuk, George Tsoulas, Oxford Univrsity Press.

In it he describes how in Middle English (down to about 1500 CE), imperatives were standardly expressed with the subject after the verb and that in negative imperatives, similarly, the negative was delayed till after the subject (as in "Judge ye not").

> a. Ne hide ou no t fram me yn comaundement.
>   Ne hide you not from me your commandment.  (The Earliest Prose Psalter 146.2169)
>   b. Depart ou nou t fro me.
>   depart you not from me  (The Earliest Prose Psalter 24.594)
>   c. medyl e not wyth hym
>   meddle you not with him   (Margery Kempe I,56.218)

In Early Modern English, (1500 to 1700), the same holds true:  in negative imperatives the order is 'verb - subject pronoun - negative.

> a. And feare ye nott them which kyll the body (310 mt10-28)
>   b. Forbid ye hym not (310 lk9-50)
>   c. doubte thou not all thinges rightly orderd be. (356 90-25)

So strictly speaking, I am far from sure that there is any literary device at the imperative end of this sentence.

So the [New International version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207%3A1&version=NIV)'s "Do not judge, or you will be judge yourselves" does deliver a plain English equivalent.  On the other hand, in the so-called Modern English Version (MEV) we find "Judge not that you be not judged", which looks like a semi-archaised copy of the King James Version!

So it is quite difficult to see what the original question is driving at.  The sentence is balanced in a certain way by means of the reciprocity between what we do and what is done to us.  But questions about literary devices and style are notoriously hard to interpret.

There is one that may be a one of the literary devices feature of the Early Modern English:  **chiasmus**.  *Chiasmus* involves balanced clauses in which the the order in the first clause is reversed in the second (AB-BA).  So "Judge not" [AB] "that ye be NOT JUDGED" [BA]

Sorry not to be more helpful.  Can the questioner not ask for guidance about the meaning of the question?  Or perhaps review whatever has already been taught about literary devices?

Comment: This is a FANTASTIC answer. I envy the scholarship, and I’d  very much like to see more of it on this site. Maybe you can bold “chiasmus”? That’s a critical contribution, IMO.

Comment: I edited the formatting of your answer here, to give it the billing it deserves. Feel free to undo it if you prefer. It’s your answer.

Comment: I obviously disagree, since _not judge lest not should-be-judged_ is a very strict parallel. And the sheer economy of the verse is hardly "plain.”

Comment: Also, given that this verse was likely transmitted through the Q source, i.e., without narrative frame, it probably was  made more economical during transmission for ease of recall. _A stitch in time saves nine_ isn't plain English either.

Comment: @KarlG What I do not know is what the Aramaic might have been like.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the order of the sentence structure?

{Judge *(Verb, imperative)* not, *(negating adverb)*} - main clause

{that *(conjunction)* ye *(subject pronoun)* be *(subjunctive present of auxiliary verb introducing a passive)* not *(negating adverb)* judged *(past participle)*} - subordinate clause.